# Conditions for quadratic form to have non zero solutions in a finite field

Tags: quadratic-forms

Does $x^TAx=0$ always have a non trivial solution when vectors are taken over $GF(k)^n$? I haven't found any counterexample yet (I was randomly trying, maybe the counterexample needs to be contructed specifically). Any thoughts?

Comment: What about the quadratic form $s^2+t^2$ over $F_3$?

Comment: Not necessarily if $n\le 2$, but yes if $n\ge3$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown That is very intersting, is the proof elementary?

Comment: @quasi I see it, Even your previous example was a correct contradiction, why did you delete it?

Comment: @Anvit: As regards my deleted comment, while it's true that the quadratic form $s^2+st+t^2$ has no nontrivial solutions in $F_2$, that form can't be realized by a $2{\times}2$ symmetric matrix $A$ with entries in $F_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non degenerate quadratic form of rang $n\geq 3$ has always a zero over a finite field (it is a standard counting argument, see below)

For rank $1$, it does not, obviously.

For rank $2$, it will have a zero if and only if it is hyperbolic (isotropic+rank 2 implies hyperbolic) if and only if its determinant is $-u^2$ for some non zero $u$.

**Proof of isotropy in rank $n\geq 3$.** Clearly, it is enough to consider the case of rank $3$ quadratic forms . It is enough to prove that, given nonzero $a,b$, any $c$ maybe written as $c=ax^2+by^2$. Note that the sets $\{c-ax^2, x\in GF(q)\}$ and $\{ by^2, y\in GF(q)\}$ both have cardinality $(q-1)/2+1$ because $a,b$ are non zero (don't forget the zero square!), so they cannot be disjoint. QED